# Repeated array elements

Tags: java

I am trying to find n repeated elements in a array. If my array size is 2N, assuming there are N+1 unique elements, and exactly one of these elements is repeated N times.

I need to return the repeated element.

```
Example 1:

Input: [1,2,3,3]
Output: 3
```

Here is my code for this. I want to have a optimal solution and find the result in constant time if possible.

```
    public class FindRepeatedElement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inputArr = new int[] {1,2,3,3};
        findRepeatedElement(inputArr);


    }


    public static void findRepeatedElement(int[] inputArr) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int count = 1;
        int match = 0;
        while(i < inputArr.length && j < inputArr.length - 1) {
            if(inputArr[i] == inputArr[j]) {
                count = count + 1;
                if(count == 3) {
                    match = inputArr[i];
                    System.out.println("MATCH " +match);
                } else {
                    j++;
                }
            }else {
                j++;        
            }

        }
     i++;
    }
}
```

I want `i` to keep getting incremented, and continue this loop. But clearly where I have `i` here, it comes out of the while loop, and increments `i`.

In short, what I want to achieve is if `i` is 0, the loop starts at `j=0`, and goes up to `< array.length`. Then I continue this for i=1, and increment `j` from 0 again. Then go to `i=2` and so on. I don't want for loops here but is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Given your problem, the solution can be just a search for the first duplicate element. You can constrain your search to n*n/2 elements. Like `for(0 <= i < array.length) { for(0 <= j < i) { if array[i] == array[j] then duplicate found! } }`

Comment: Don't use nested loops for this; it's better use a HashSet to test whether the element has been "seen" already. But for this particular problem we can do it in O(n) time and O(1) space too.

Comment: *"find the result in constant time if possible."* You can probably achieve constant time in the average case, but any correct algorithm is definitely at least linear time in the worst case; you might look at *n* / 2 elements before you see a single instance of the repeated element, let alone confirm it has a duplicate.

Comment: I know other ways to do this clearly. For my algo, is there an option to do it?

Answer (score 3):

When an element occurs very frequently in a sequence, it is useful to consider the fact that if more than 50% of the elements are equal, then there must be two *adjacent* occurrences of it. If we were guaranteed that N+1 of the elements in a 2N-element array were equal (and the rest were distinct), then we could just scan adjacent pairs and stop when we find the first adjacent pair which are equal. This would take O(N) time and O(1) auxiliary space.

For your problem we are not quite guaranteed this, because there are N copies of the repeated element in a 2N-element array. But we can deduce a limit on how spaced-out the occurrences of the equal element can be: if there is no adjacent pair of occurrences, then the pattern must look like one of these cases (E for the equal element, dot for any other element).

- `E.E.E.E.E.E.E.` evenly spaced, two apart.
- `.E.E.E.E.E.E.E` evenly spaced, two apart.
- `E.E.E..E.E.E.E` evenly spaced, two apart, but one gap is 3.

We can *almost* guarantee that there must be a pair of occurrences spaced two apart, except there is a special case when N = 2 of `E..E`. In that case, they are spaced three apart. So, there is a straightforward algorithm which takes O(N) time and O(1) auxiliary space: for each index `i`, compare `arr[i]` with `arr[i+1]`, `arr[i+2]` and `arr[i+3]`. If it equals any of those, then you've found the repeated element.

A slightly cleverer algorithm is to compare `arr[0] == arr[2]` (covering the first special case), then `arr[1] == arr[3]` (for the second special case), then `arr[0] == arr[arr.length - 1]` (for the third special case, including `E..E`). If none of those finds the repeated element, then for each `i` we only need to test `arr[i] == arr[i+1]` to find it.

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

> and exactly one of these elements is repeated N times.

Based on this, I would use a Set like so :

```
public static int findRepeated(int[] inputArr) {
    Set<Integer> list = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (Integer i : inputArr) {
        if (list.contains(i)) {
            return i;
        } else {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No repeated Element");
}
```

---

and If you are using Java8, then you can use `collect` with `groupingBy` and counting like so :

```
Integer rep = Arrays.stream(inputArr)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No repeated Element"));
```

Answer (score 0):

With nested loops:

```java
  public static void findRepeatedElement(int[] inputArr) {
    for (int i = 1; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (inputArr[i] == inputArr[j]) {
          System.out.printf("found duplicates at %d and %d (%d)", i, j, inputArr[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Worst case (an array without duplicates) is O(n²). Actually, this code will always scan `(n-1)*n/2` elements, because it does not quit on the first duplicate found; it will also find all duplicate pairs.